# Invalid value for 'Event'-Property (XAML Eventsetter)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and I get the following error message:

> Invalid value for 'Event'-Property:
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.XmlValue.

Here's the code behind:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="Check_MouseEnter" />
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="Check_MouseLeave" />
    <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="Check_GotFocus" />
```

I've tried `UIElement.MouseEnter`, `Mouse.MouseEnter`, `TextBox.MouseEnter`. If I compile the handler works just fine, but the error message is still there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems a bug in the WPF designer, as already reported [here on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1611888/xaml-editor-error-invalid-value-for-property-handler-and-ischecked-bug-remains-in-the-enterprise-version-of-vs-2015).

It seems that the designer falsely gives an warning or error, but eventually the code is okay, so it compiles and works. Nothing you should worry about now, since the product isn't released yet.

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond. I've also found this post, but they mentioned, that this bug was already fixed in their latest build (4 month ago).

Comment: Well, they *said* they fixed it in the next build. Maybe it didn't get through the whole process or the bug is still there.

Comment: I just saw it as an Intellisense error in VS2015 RTM

Comment: is that the correct microsoft connect link? it shows something about a checkbox state rather than a handler.

Comment: No. It is not. Fixing now.

Comment: eight years and a few VS versions later (17.4.4), still no fix... and no, I won't say "nothing to worry about", if you start to ignore warnings because they are potentially due to Microsoft laziness, how will you differentiate real warnings amongst wrong warnings?

Comment: Furthermore, this "warning" prevents the WPF Designer from automatically refreshing right after I modify any XAML file. Comment out the `EventSetter` tag and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, 7.5 years after this question, the bug is [fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/WPF-Designer-Invalid-value-for-property/10208510) since VS 2022 version 17.5 Preview 2.

On the Release channel, the fix is expected to be available from February 2023.

Comment: In June 2023 it seems to have been resolved in three places where it used to occur before in a Wpf .Net6.0 project