# DataGrid Event Handler has an error that prevents the live view from being updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, eventhandler

I am having an interesting issue. I am using Visual Studio 2022. In my XAML code, I have a DataGrid with EventSetter. The Handler is alerting on "Invalid value for property 'Handler'. This error prevents the live view from being updated. I have either to rebuild the project or remove the EventSetter and write it back every time for the live view to update.

Is it something that I have to resolve in the VS setup or the code behind?

[image]

I was trying to add an Event Handler for DataGrid. It is successfully working but the Handler has an error. This prevents the live view from refreshing, when I am making changes on the XAML code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid value for 'Event'-Property (XAML Eventsetter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378433/invalid-value-for-event-property-xaml-eventsetter)

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew for bringing this answer. I was under impression that it might be a bug. The link takes me to an issue experienced in VS2015. I am using VS2022. Can't conclude yet if this is a bug, or might be something else....
Will wait for more suggestions.